# SQL get ID of a row on another table that contains the same characters in a certain column

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I'm practicing some SQL and I came across a situation where I have two tables.  They both have 'name' columns in them and one table has id's and one does not.  I want to grab the id of the name row and add the ID of that row to the other tables same name row.

```
Table A
ID, Name
1, Ryan
2, Chris
3, Ben

Table B
ID, Name
null, Ryan
null, Chris
null, Ben
```

So basically, I need to grab the name of table B, find the row in Table A that has the matching 'Name' column, grab the ID and add it to the empty ID column in Table B

Comment: do you have to `update` table B?

Comment: @vkp yes, i need to update the empty ID column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 SELECT ta.id as id_a, ta.name, tb.id as id_b 
 FROM TABLE_A as ta
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_B as tb
 ON ta.name = tb.name;
```

**Update**

Didn't notice that you need to update the col id on Table B.

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE TABLE_B as tb,
(
   SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
)  as ta
SET tb.id = ta.id WHERE tb.name = ta.name;
```

Comment: The latest seems to work however its throwing "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Comment: Oh, do you have the same names inside Table B?

Comment: @ryan If you have, then you should create new columns for the update id instead. Since your col ID currently is a PRIMARY key which should be UNIQUE.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot guys.  The SQL was mixing up table A and B so it was trying to add the ID to table B, which already had the PK.  Thanks a lot!